# How to access to element of json file in local host?

Tags: json, angularjs

I need to select an element from my data with my **$resource**, but I have this error :

> "Error: $produit1 is not defined GET XHR
>   http://localhost:8080/Jquery/data/produits.json/1  [HTTP/1.1 404
>   Introuvable 15ms]

I Think the problem comes from this url: http://localhost:8080/Jquery/data/**produits.json/1**

because this url http://localhost:8080/Jquery/data/produits.json  is OK when i put it on my browser i can see the data, the first dont show me the data (Etat HTTP 404 - /Jquery/data/produits.json/1 )

```
[
{
"id" : 1,
"reference": "AAA",
},
{
"id" : 2,
"reference": "BBB",
}
]
```

How can I call my elements by the url please ?

Here is my code :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Angular ngResource</title>
    <script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

        myApp.factory('Produits',['$resource', function ($resource) {
            return $resource('data/produits.json/:id',{id: "@id"},
                     {
                        'update': {method: 'PUT'},
                        'reviews': {method: 'GET'}
                     }
            );
        }]);

        myApp.controller('produitsCtrl', function($scope, $http,Produits,$log) {

        $scope.produits= Produits.query();

        $scope.produit1 = Produits.get({'id': 1});

        });


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div ng-app="myApp" >

            <div ng-controller="produitsCtrl"> 

                Reference  1 :  {{ produit1.reference }}
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If you just have a web server serving static JSON files, there's no wayt this static web server will open the file for you, read the array as JSON, find the product with the ID 1 and return you just the object when sending a request to /Jquery/data/produits.json/1. All it can do is look if there is a file named `1` in the directory `/Jquery/data/produits.json/`. You need a real dynamic backend, interpreting your requests and dynamically sending JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that your call :

```
$resource('data/produits.json/:id',{id: "@id"},
```

is looking for a json that is generated regarding the id you pass. So your app expects to have a json file that exists only if in your route id=1 exists and returns a json.

```
$scope.produit1 = Produits.get({'id': 1});
```

should return a json file with elements as the ones you have currently.

If you want to use the datas contained in your json you need to do this :

```
 var Produits = $resource(data/produits.json);

 myApp.controller('produitsCtrl', function($scope, $http,Produits,$log) {
              var upd = {
                 "id": 1,
                 "reference": "REF"
              }

              Produits.$update(upd.id);

         });
```

Comment: thks, can you see my answer above